# How can I show worldCopyJump in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm having some problems with the dateline in leaflet. What I would like to do is pretty simple :

**Show worldCopyJump on the left and right map at the same time**

The idea is to be able to draw a line/points between 179 and -179 and see them duplicated without having the need to jump to the other world

[image]

As you can see there is a problem with the polyline (I think I can deal with it). If I have `worldCopyJump` on true I can switch on another world at the right and have the next part of the polyline.

I think that [Marine traffic](https://www.marinetraffic.com) is doing it or there are duplicating markers.

And OpenLayer seems to have the perfect option: [open layers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled-wrap-180.html) by using `wrapx`

Any idea on how to do it ? My current solution is not the best since I'm checking if it cross the dateline and then add 360 to the longitude.

Comment: FYI, [OSM website](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) uses Leaflet. OpenLayers seems to suffer from the same limitation as Leaflet regarding the antimeridian, e.g. see OpenLayers [issue #3937](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/3937). The example you mention is about WMS tiles, which are indeed easy to re-use on copies of the world. Same example with Leaflet: https://plnkr.co/edit/PWhSr6BQMKcOZx7TuJfZ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but I think that I wasn't clear enough because the link was an example of an `infinite` (3 worlds) map like marine traffic. The objective is not to have the label but to be able to draw lines between 179 and -179. I will update my question

Comment: A bit late to the party but using D3 to generate your SVGs removes the antimeridian problem

Comment: @TomMcLean What svg are you talking about ? The track ?

Comment: @Baptiste Yep, I have just written some code to plot D3 and Leaflet together if its of any of use to you still I will write an answer

Comment: @TomMcLean Well, I'm always looking for better way to do things. My current solution was to use points after 180°. Is zooming an issue while using SVG ? I remember that you need to redraw it everytime.

Comment: @Baptise I brute forced a method until it worked for zooming, panning etc. This is the result: https://imgur.com/a/Np7hd38 It  D3 deals with the antimeridian better than any other library, as well as doing adaptive sampling for the SVGs (and also draws great circles by default, which is what I needed it for). I do end up redrawing the SVG on every zoom, but you don't need to when you pan

Comment: @TomMcLean Nice ! Can you handle different colors in the track ? I need it to display the speed (for now I'm using a plugin for threshold).

Comment: Can you send a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: @TomMcLean Here is the library I'm using: http://hgoebl.github.io/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/demo/